# VBA Excel - Replacing exact word in a String Phrase

Tags: string, vba, excel, replace

I have an array with some words that  i want to replace with other words, in fact, i have some problem:

Eg:

- Var1 ->  wksArray
- Var2 -> wksArrayBigger
- string : Dim wksArray,   wksArrayBigger as Variant

When i try to replace wksArray with "test1", it will cause:

- var1 -> teste1
- var2 -> test1Bigger
- string : Dim teste1, teste1Bigger  as Variant

How can i solve that?

```
Function FindAndReplace(VBProjToClean, varArray)
Dim i, b As Integer
Dim str, replace_str As String
Dim VBC As VBComponent
    For Each VBC In VBProjToClean.VBComponents
            i = 1
            With VBC.CodeModule
                Do Until i > .CountOfLines
                    If Not .ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc) = "VBE_Remove_Comments" Then
                        str = .Lines(i, 1)
                    End If
                    For b = 1 To UBound(varArray)
                        If InStr(1, str, varArray(b), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                           replace_str = Replace(str, varArray(b), varArray(b) & "banana")
                           .ReplaceLine i, replace_str
                            str = .Lines(i, 1)
                        End If
                    Next b
                i = i + 1
                Loop
            End With
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Stricter conditional logic (i.e., test for exact match/etc.) or use regular expressions.

Comment: In relation to above comment, have a look at `CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")` to use regular expressions in your code.

Answer (score 0):

While not a proper fix to your problem, you could sort your search list and possibly add some intermediary replacements should there be conflicts you cant resolve.

```
arrReplaceBigger -> arIM01
arrReplace -> aR
arIM01 -> aRB '
```

If your just replacing variable names, you could create a function to replace `Replace` that would do a number of extra replacements, appending however many possibilities for the next character there are.

```
white-space, comma, period, left bracket, right bracket, new line, plus, ...., etc
```

Or instead of doing many extra replacements you could do the same thing using Regular Expressions as David suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to find out if something is a valid character for a VBA variable
Then for each pear of strings,
Look for the occurences of the string to be replaced, verify that preceding and succeding positoins do not contain valid characters, and if so, replace the string.